# Where does the word “jism” come from?

Tags: etymology, slang, offensive-language

Another word of mysterious origins of *jism*, in the sense of spunk.  The OED mentions it is sometimes spelled *jizz*, and may even be the precursor word to *jazz*.

[image: jazz pix]

But neither the OED nor Etymonline gives any etymology for this word. The oldest citation is from 1847, and there are many citations from the 20<sup>th</sup> century.

So where do we get the word *jism* from?

Comment: Where do tchrist's umpteen batched doubts come from?

Comment: Perhaps it may be wise to ask "where does **the word** jism come from" so as not to invite the most literal of answers!

Comment: Precursor to "jazz"? Yeah, possibly. Maybe that's why singer/songwriter Leonard Cohen intones "Jazz police are looking through my folders 
 Jazz police are talking to my niece 
 Jazz police have got their final orders 
 Jazzer, drop your axe, it's Jazz police!"

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/129577/2085) and [definitely related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/142491).

Comment: @Ste So you’re saying that it’s related to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/142947), eh? :)

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jism) says 'of uncertain origin' Others give some kind of [West African source](https://thetell.wordpress.com/2007/08/11/concerning-the-etymology-of-jism/) amid other speculation.

Comment: Is it possible that "jism" is a play off the word, as well as a shortened version, of "orgasm? The letter 'g' can sound like a 'j' within several words. Just a thought.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Not within earshot of OED: *If the truth were known about the origin of the word '[Jazz](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jazz&allowed_in_frame=0)' it would never be mentioned in polite society. ["Étude," Sept. 1924]* )

---

Entirely possible that it is drawn from the Hindi [जिस्म](http://dict.hinkhoj.com/words/meaning-of-jism-in-english.html)  (*jism*):

> 1. देह। बदन। शरीर। 2. २. स्त्री या पुरुष का गुप्त अंग। भग या लिंग
> 2. Body. 2. Female or male genitals. Vulva or penis

?Whence,

> "seminal fluid, cum," 1899; earlier "energy, strength" (1842) ([etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jism))

also **jissom** /ˈdʒɪsəm/  *vulgar slang* semen. ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jism))

commentary: The Hindi word is pronounced /ˈdʒɪsm/ in formal speech and /ˈdʒɪsəm/ in regular/ vulgar use, as is the English word per ODO.

Comment: Its is not completely true what you have reference from Hindi Dictionary

Comment: @AmitRanjan I'd be interested if you have anything else to cite instead. Are you quoting this from some source or is that your opinion? (Same goes about your 'answer'.)

Comment: Actuall kris it means only Human body nothing else. It has no specific relations with genitals, but its also true that such things are part of it. I am from india and its a common word here, not a slang or offensive language. Yes sometimes it sounds funny.

Comment: We are not discussing opinions, we need to find canonical answers. Anything in support will be helpful and useful to everyone here. (While you can always post your opinions in comments, they cannot be used to post answers or to disagree with other answers, naturally?)

Comment: Balderdash, absolutely speculative answer. There is absolutely no way the US jism derives from the Hindi jism. The timelines are entirely different, and in any case the Hindi word just means "body" and is not typically used in any sexual sense.
Jizz/jism is turn of the century American slang, one hardly meets it outside cheap period literature, and there is no way this is influenced by an Indian word. @Kris's own source says Creole/African.

Answer (score 4):

In Ryan and Jetha's *Sex at Dawn* (2010, Ch. 5), they suggest that both 'jism' and 'jazz' come from the Ki-Kongo word *dinza*, meaning "to ejaculate", citing Robert Farris Thompson's *Flash of the Spirit* (1984) and Ventura's essay "Hear that Long Snake Moan" (1986).

Culturally, rooting this word in an African language seems more likely to me than in an Indian one (as is suggested in a few posts above).

Answer (score 1):

If it’s really ***jism*** then it is primarily an Urdu word that means “human body”, in common use on the Indian Subcontinent and also in some Arabic-speaking countries.

It isn’t slang or offensive there.  Yes, it sounds a little bit funny, but it isn’t really.