# When did people start "boinking"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english, slang

Is "boinking" an onomatopoeic and/or a [blend word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word)?

I would have said so, I believe the word *boink* refers to the sound of the mattress springs squeaking under the weight of a couple making love. A slang term which derives from a "blending" of *boing* and *bonk*. But I have found precious little information to confirm it. Do native speakers use the word "boink" to also imitate the sound of mattress springs or *only* as a jocular (is it vulgar?) substitution for *having sex*?

Oxford Dictionaries says:

> - [**boing**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/boing)
>   Origin 1950s: imitative.
> - [**bonk**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bonk)
>   Origin 1930s: imitative.
>   British; have sexual intercourse (also North American *boink*)
> - [**boink**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/bonk?q=boink)
>   ?

There is no entry. OD directs the visitor back to *bonk*

Luckily, Merriam-Webster believes *boink* deserves more attention.

> - **[boink](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boink)**
>   Origin: boink, boing, interjections imitative of a reverberating sound
>   First Known Use: **1987**

Etymology Online has

> - **[boink](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=boink)**
>   "have sex with; the sex act," slang by **c.2000**, perhaps an alteration
>   of *bonk* in its popular sexual sense. Related: *Boinked*; *boinking*.
> - **[bonk](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bonk&allowed_in_frame=0)**
>   "to hit," 1931, probably of imitative origin; **1975** in sense of
>   "have sexual intercourse with." Related: *Bonked*; *bonking*.

I read somewhere that the actor Bruce Willis first coined the expression *boink* in the TV series *Moonlighting*. Is it true? I'm positive I was "boinking" and "boinked" in the early 80s, but not in the 70s because I was only a child.

Comment: I suspect the repetitious, long-common *boing-boing-boing* of bouncing (e.g. on a pogo stick) should be considered in how boink came to be understood as sex.

Comment: As for Bruce Willis: Episode 4 "The Next Murder You Hear" 
March 19, 1985

The Hokey Pokey; variation (Mr. Stickpin) performed by Bruce Willis
Respect by Aretha Franklin; performed by Bruce Willis
Powerhouse B by Raymond Scott; variation (Boink, Boink, Boink) performed by Bruce Willis
Episode 5 "Next Stop Murder"
March 26, 1985:http://home.comcast.net/~christinemgraves/mlmusic.html

Comment: Look, I've asked the question. Post whatever findings, I won't downvote anyone who attempts to answer it. @Josh61 that last link (now deleted) was good!

Comment: (I cannot believe a lady would ask such a tarty question!) FWIW presently (today), I'd say generally **bonking** in both AmE or BrE.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nU3AIvfK04  they're so good aren't they?  never been anyone like 'em.  i'd guess, surely, that scene just "popularised" it - it was not a shakespearean-esque creation of the term ex-nihilo

Comment: @JoeBlow thanks for the link!  Weren't they just beautiful to look at? Willis was gorgeous *and* funny. Shepherd was only stunning to look at.

Comment: Right, people forget B.W. was, is, a major intellectual-comic genius, like say Buster Keaton. Both of their voices are just stunning instruments.  I melt when I hear either of them talk. Her presentation of her character in ML is a masterwork of our age, she's the most beautiful gal in the universe, the epitome of social-cultural issues of our day (presented in purest comedy). It's not that the show is a "forgotten masterpiece" but along the lines, it's extremely highly considered and becoming more so with every passing decade. It's brilliant

Comment: Partridge (NPDOSUE 2008) has "**boink** _noun_ an in-person meeting of participants in an Internet
discussion group _US, 1995_ ||
**boink** _verb_ to have sex with someone _US, 1897_" - but no attribution so ... that could be a typo and it's 1978/1987/1997/1979 etc.

Comment: 1897?! Must be a typo, but 1987 (M-W also has this date) looks too recent.

Comment: Partridge (NPDOSUE 2008) also has "**bonk** _verb_ ... 2 to have sex _UK, 1975_" and I would think _bonk_ predated _boink_ so maybe a typo for 1897.

Comment: I'm no biologist, but I'm fairly sure people have been boinking since the dawn of the species. ;-)

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142947/where-does-the-word-ag-come-from/145807#145807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It's been bugging me for ages this "boink".)

The earliest instance I found *boink*,  used unequivocally as a verb, is in an electrical engineering volume called *[R & D Review](https://www.google.it/search?q=The%20analogous%20picture%20in%20a%20simple%20mechanical%20model&oq=The%20analogous%20picture%20in%20a%20simple%20mechanical%20model&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22oil+can+just+as+it+%22boinks%22:%22)*, **1957**.

> The analogous picture in a simple mechanical model is that of the bottom of anold-fashioned [sic] oil can just as it **“boinks”**: there are two stable states separated by an energy barrier. If we had not included the spontaneous distortion (for instance, if the lattice were incompressible but still thermally expansive), then on increasing temperature the interaction energy characterized by T1 …

Thanks also to @josh61's post, I was spurred to watch the American sitcom *Cheers* for myself.  I viewed the entire 11 seasons (1982-1993), and I discovered the term *boink*, meaning sexual intercourse, was uttered twice in season 3. At that time the shows  were written by a staff of writers among whom were David Angell, Peter Casey and David Lee who later worked together in the spin-off show *Frasier*, 1993-2004. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheers_(season_3)), the writers in episode 2 were Glen Charles & Les Charles, and episode 22 was written by Sam Simon (co-creator of *The Simpsons*).

The first utterance of *boink* occurs in episode 2, *Rebound: Part 2*

In [*Rebound: Part 2*](http://gorillavid.in/b2kj53tj8fcn) the umpteenth waitress hired to replace Diane Chambers quits her job when she discovers the sex-obsessed but charismatic bar owner, Sam Malone, has bedded her sister. Carla Tortelli (played by Rhea Perlman), Sam's most loyal employee, exasperated by the number of waitresses who quit, tells him:

> (0.15.15) Carla: Great, great. Now I've gotta work another Saturday night by myself. Sam you promised you weren't going to boink any more waitresses in this joint unless it was me!

*Boink* appeared again in episode 22 ["Cheerio Cheers"](http://gorillavid.in/nqirs3ve8wz2) but this time as a noun.  The following line is delivered at h0.20.02.

> Carla: Well, last I saw, you and Diane were here alone. D’ja give her a goodbye boink?

Episode 2 was aired **October 4, 1984** whilst episode 22 was filmed in [late November 1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheers_(season_3)#Production), and aired April 11, 1985. Meanwhile Stephen King's novel, *[Thinner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinner_(novel))*, mentioned in @snailboat's answer was published in **November 19, 1984**.

<sub><sup>LINK TO [*CHEERS*](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=cheers&episode=s03e02) SCRIPTS.</sup></sub>

Comment: Interesting, but perhaps completely unrelated to the verb sense of _boink_: Herb Hendler, [_Year by Year in the Rock Era_](https://books.google.com/books?id=j2mXpJJTZvYC&pg=PA60&dq=%22boink%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBDgUahUKEwjvgoHz3c3HAhUOK4gKHYSTCm8#v=onepage&q=%22boink%22&f=false) (1983) reports this use of _boink_ under the heading "Some of the More Widely Used Argot, Jargon and Slang in the Rock Era," for the year 1962: "Boink (stupid)..." The usage seems more closely related to "bonking [hitting] on the head"

Comment: @SvenYargs I even found a 1960 Hanna Barbera, Yogi Bear, cartoon titled ["Oinks and Boinks"](http://yowpyowp.blogspot.com/2012/06/yogi-bear-oinks-and-boinks.html) with a sort of alliterative meaning :)

Comment: Another Hanna Barbera cartoon character of the same vintage as Yogi Bear was a Wild West sheriff (and horse) named Quick Draw McGraw, who had a masked and caped alter ego patterned on Zorro, and named "El Kabong"; El Kabong's signature method of capturing crooks was to bong/bonk/boink them on the head with his guitar.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like [*Thinner* was actually written in 1982](http://awood.blogspot.com/2012/08/stephen-king-thinner-as-richard-bachman.html), although it wasn't published until 1984.

Comment: @snailboat a manuscript is not really the same as a book that is ready to be published. It would be really cool if someone where to write to King and ask if he wrote *He half-expected them to begin bopping and boinking each other.* in the original manuscript though! But for argument's sake let's say he did, would that still count? A coined expression that was not exposed to the public until two years later, I'm not sure if it's "legal" to say King coined it first.

Comment: Well, the written record is usually an approximation―most words like these are coined in speech before they appear in writing.  For the purposes of antedating, it doesn't really matter when something was published or aired, just when it was created.

Answer (score 17):

The OED dates *boink* as a verb back to 1984, citing [Stephen King's *Thinner*](http://books.google.com/books?id=KKhBiyI3rngC&pg=PT105&dq=%22He+half-expected+them+to+begin+bopping+and+boinking+each+other%22&sa=X&ei=OpMeVITfLdXkoATehYCoBQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22He%20half-expected%20them%20to%20begin%20bopping%20and%20boinking%20each%20other%22&f=false), where it appears to be used as onomatopoeia, similar to *bonk*:

> He half-expected them to begin bopping and boinking each other.

For this sense, the OED gives the definition "to strike, to knock", which is fairly similar to how *bonk* is used.  As for the sexual meaning, their earliest cite is from two years later, [a 1986 posting to the newsgroup *net.singles* by Andrew Tannenbaum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/net.singles/6Ac3NBlNA-Q/Q6dLaZRdNVQJ):

> When you and your honey boink away, you're doing what the doggies do.

Can *boink* be antedated?  Perhaps.  But take a look at the following chart from [Google Books Ngrams Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boink%2Cboinking&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cboink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboinking%3B%2Cc0):

[image: boink and boinking chart]

So at the very least, *boink* wasn't widespread until after the mid-80s.

Searching Google Books, I was able to find some examples of *boink* from before 1986, but none with a sexual meaning.  I chose to search for [*boinking*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boinking%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1960,cd_max:1990&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) first to reduce false positives because Google Books (unlike their Ngram Viewer) is case-insensitive and *Boink* is a name.  I did also search for [*boink*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boink%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1960,cd_max:1980&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl), but it was less useful.  Searches for [*boinked*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ShEQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22boinked%22&dq=%22boinked%22&sa=X&ei=xpgeVPTvIIvsoASktILoAw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBA) and [*boinks*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ShEQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22boinked%22&dq=%22boinks%22&sa=X&ei=xpgeVPTvIIvsoASktILoAw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBA) had fewer false positives than *boink* did, but neither turned up any pre-1986 citations with a sexual meaning.

Most of what I found was like the following snippet from [*The Complaint Booth* (Jack Kurtz, 1978)](http://books.google.com/books?id=0hldXwzXIs4C&pg=PA42&dq=%22boinking%22&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=CZQeVKroBpPloASJsIGYDg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22fairies%20pass%20through%20audience%20boinking%20people%20with%20their%20wands%22&f=false):

> *Fairies pass through audience boinking people with their wands. Elves up and down aisles "beeping."*

Here it seems similar to *bonk*.  And we can find scattered earlier uses with the same meaning, as in the following 1966 use with a similar meaning in [*Science & Technology*](http://books.google.com/books?id=SGUjAQAAMAAJ&q=%22boinking%22&dq=%22boinking%22&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=0pQeVIziDMa5ogSN1oDACA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwATgK):

> This causes a mechanical wave to travel around the circumference of the sleeve―in the same way it would if you kept "boinking" the top of a metal can with your fingers.

Using the same tools, [Frank](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197514/when-did-people-start-boinking/197526?noredirect=1#comment417015_197526) found an even earlier example, apparently quoting something [Senator John Thye said in a 1947 congressional committee meeting](http://books.google.com/books?ei=SZseVIbYDoqsogS4qILADQ&id=4CXRAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=boink):

> Mr. Sears, how would you propose to perfect the general farm program, disregarding soil conservation which is just one small phase of the enter program, but boink back to parity price, the ever-normal granary, and those programs?

There are more like this, but it didn't seem to be especially common and none of the pre-1986 examples I found had a sexual meaning.  Of course, that doesn't mean people didn't use it that way, only that I can't find it in print using online tools.  It seems likely that the word was used in speech before it appeared in print, but I can only speculate as to how much earlier.

Given the dates, including the citation Frank found, it seems reasonable to guess that *boink* goes back about as far as *bonk*.  As for the sexual use, it seems safe to say it became commonplace after the mid-80s.

Comment: 1948 - boink as bounce? http://books.google.com/books?id=yvBhEdm3JsAC&q=boink&dq=boink&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TJkeVN_7OMvbuQSxxoHQBA&redir_esc=y

Comment: If that's the same Andrew Tanenbaum that wrote MINX, I'm starting to see a pattern here.

Comment: Do you think *boink* is a blending of *boing* and bonk*, or simply a spelling variation of *bonk*? Your earlier references seem to indicate that "boink" original meant to either tap  people (gently) on their heads or spring energetically forward/backward?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Dictionaries relate it to *bonk* and that makes sense to me, too, although I wouldn't personally call it a *spelling* variation because the pronunciation is also different.  My intuition says *boink* is more closely related to *bonk* than *boing*, but I can't say with confidence how the word developed.  The citation Frank found does seem more like *boing* than *bonk*, but most of the examples I found seemed more like *bonk* to me (onomatopoeia for some kind of blunt-force collision).

Comment: On the BrEng chart, *boinks* and *bonked* are not mapped, which I suppose is proof that the term, boink originated from the US. Is *boink* considered vulgar in the US? (I can't imagine it to be so).

Comment: @Mari-Lou I don't have much to add to what I've already written, but I can try to answer your last question: it's not really vulgar, just informal, in my opinion.  If anything, it sounds a bit silly to me.

Answer (score 8):

According to the following [source](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/alt.usage.english/vD2OQaVNfr0) the usage of 'boink' by David Angell in the American sitcom 'Cheers' may have predated  Bruce Willis's line in 1985.

> But it seems likely now that *Cheers* used it first, though not very long
>   before. Les Charles, one of the creators of *Cheers*, said, in remarks
>   delivered at the memorial service for David Angell (and his wife, who
>   also died in the September 11th incident):  "And lest we forget, if he'd
>   never done another thing in his career, David Angell would have earned
>   immortality as the man who added the word boink to the English language."
>
> - *It looks like Angell worked as a writer for _Cheers_ mainly in 1983* and
>     1984, i.e., the first few seasons of the show; he then went on to work as
>     story editor and producer.  Presumably any use of 'boink' attributable to
>     Angell's writing would have been during 1983-1984, predating the 1985 
>     use on *Moonlighting*.  I've not yet seen any concrete evidence that
>     'boink' was ever used on *Soap* other than what's said in the Jargon File
>     entry.

Source: www.groups.google.com/forum

The following  [sentence](http://chambersandmalone.tumblr.com/) is from Cheers scripts episode 'Sam and Diane Day' **in 1983.**

> - "Well, last I saw, you and Diane were here alone.  *D’ja give her a goodbye boink?"*

- The actress  Carla Tortelli, who appeared in all episodes of Cheers in 1982–1993 ( referring to David Angell):

> - **"He invented the word boink.**  Which came from Sam and Diane were boinking, and they were looking for a euphemism for that, and David thought of the word boink.  It has since entered the lexicon, which actually, I spoke about that at his memorial service, as part of his legacy."

Source: www.chambersandmalone.tumblr.com

Comment: Stephen King's *boink* (sexual intercourse) is dated 1984. Maybe if you scoured the Internet for *Cheers* show scripts you might find an earlier reference?

Comment: No, the conclusion is that *boink* (meaning to hit, and heavily related to *bonk*) existed before it came to be associated with the sexual act. David Angell did not create/invent the actual term *boink*, perhaps he was the first to give it a sexual meaning. In your answer, you allude to the fact that the script writer "invented" the word, which isn't strictly true.

Comment: "Carla Tortelli" is the character from the show, *Rhea Perlman* is the actress.

Comment: The  cited year 1983 is incorrect, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a group of teenagers in a small school in Sleaford, Lincolnshire, England who started using the word "bonk" to mean have sex in about 1970. We have always maintained that we "invented" it having never knowingly heard it used before. We set out on a mission to "spread the word". Maybe we were delusional or could it be that we succeeded?

Comment: Apparently, the British started  [*bonking*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bonk) in the 1970s :)